# how to change the background color of message box in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Actually, windows phone provide default message box with black background. I am already using custom message box using its toolkit. It has background property but I am unable to assign any value. It gives type casting error.

hope so someone will tell the right value, I alreay tried (0,0,0,0) / "grey" / colors.grey but same error

```
CustomMessageBox msgbox = new CustomMessageBox()
{
Caption = "Memory Race",
Message ="This is custom message box!",
LeftButtonContent = "OK",
Background = "what?"
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set backgroundcolor

```
Background =  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Comment: thank you its perfect
what if I want to set back-ground image ?

Comment: whenever I apply image for back-ground; it makes it transparent
var bg = new ImageBrush();
            bg.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Assets\bg.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
{
Background = bg
}

Comment: are you getting the image in bg?

Comment: background.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"SplashScreenImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: yes, bg has image, the code is same to yours, but I included library

Answer (score 0):

Background property is a color brush.
You must do this:

```
*.Background = new SolidColorBrush(ConvertStringToColor("#0D0D0E"));

private Color ConvertStringToColor(String hex)
    {
        //remove the # at the front
        hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

        byte a = 255;
        byte r = 255;
        byte g = 255;
        byte b = 255;

        int start = 0;

        //handle ARGB strings (8 characters long)
        if (hex.Length == 8)
        {
            a = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            start = 2;
        }

        //convert RGB characters to bytes
        r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
    }
```

Comment: whenever I apply image for back-ground; it makes it transparent var bg = new ImageBrush(); bg.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Assets\image.jpg", UriKind.Relative)); { Background = bg }

Comment: how can I set Image for background ?

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0b524088-fdac-4114-a2a1-a3b9b8c55d80/custommessagebox-button-color?forum=wpdevelop) and stylize your CustomMessageBox