# Is there a way to define different foreground colors in my CustomMessageBox from WindowsPhone 8 Toolkit?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, messagebox, windows-phone-toolkit

I was wondering, whether it is possible to style the CustomMessageBox from Windows Phone 8 Toolkit more precisely?

In this case, I'd like to have different foreground colors for the Caption and for the actual Message / the button text/border.

Can I define the Box in XAML as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424662/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-message-box-in-wp8

Comment: @d.lavysh I've already read that link. I'm asking for the possibility to change the **Foreground** color! I know how to change the ForegroundColor for both (Caption and Message) together, but I'd like to have different colors for each of them.
Do you have an idea / other link where this is explained?

Comment: No I think you can't. This would break Wp8 design guidelines. If you need to do this for some reasons, you could create your own CustomMessageBox or you download the [sources](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and add dependency properties for caption and content text and borders.

Comment: Hi, Is there a simple way to change the ForegroundColor for both (Caption and Message) together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be too much effort.  All you have to do is subclass `CustomMessageBox`, add dependency properties for the separate foreground colors, and then modify the default control template.  (You will see that default template uses the same `Foreground` property for the title, caption, message, and button.)

As an example, let's take the title color.  First add a dependency property:

```
public class ExtendedCustomMessageBox : CustomMessageBox
{
    public Brush TitleForeground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(TitleForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleForegroundProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TitleForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ExtendedCustomMessageBox), null);

    public CustomMessage()
        : base()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomMessageBox);
    }
}
```

Now modify the appropriate part of the control template.  Use a `TemplateBinding` to reference the new property:

```
<TextBlock 
    x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
    Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
    Foreground="{TemplateBinding TitleForeground}"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    Margin="24,16,24,-6"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
```

(Note that you can find the full control template in the WP8 toolkit download, in the file `Themes\Generic.xaml`.  Just copy-paste into your project's resources, and modify.)

Comment: This looks like a great approach I should've thought myself of. However, my template seems not to be recognized/used. Do I have to reference it in any special way?

Comment: Forget it. Great thing. Working like charm. I just changed "Title" and it did not work, but I wanted to change "Caption" and because I had no title, nothing changed ... great story, huh? 30minutes of my life wasted with this ...
THANKS for your help! :)